# How to calculate distance and duration of a route using the Google Matrix API

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps-api-3

I'm stuck in one place, where I am trying to fetch duration and distance using the Google Matrix API. Multiple routes may be available for the specified source and destination. I want to calculate duration for a specific route among available route options.

Is there any way available in Google Matrix to do that?

Any pointers or help will be appreciated.

Comment: May you provide your code so far?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=18.5099568,73.7791501&destinations=20.3893155,72.9106202&mode=driving&departure_time=1510665050&key=yourapikey

I called above URL using javascript which returns me distance and time from specified source to destination.but here what I want let's say from the map I got one root where I have multiple chunks of latitude and longitude to rich the destination.but how I can get distance and time for that root.

Comment: Yes, the Google Maps Distance Matrix API returns the total distance and travel time between each source and destination location specified. But how to extract these informations mostly depends on how you interact with the API... Are you using the official JavaScript client library (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), or are you interacting directly with the webservice?

Comment: No, I am using restTemplate(spring) to call this URL.